# ¿Como instalo amcharts local?

Tags: javascript, amcharts

En este ejemplo funciona perfecto.

```js
var chartData = [ {
    "country": "USA",
    "visits": 4252
  }, {
    "country": "China",
    "visits": 1882
  }, {
    "country": "Japan",
    "visits": 1809
  }, {
    "country": "Germany",
    "visits": 1322
  }, {
    "country": "UK",
    "visits": 1122
  }, {
    "country": "France",
    "visits": 1114
  }, {
    "country": "India",
    "visits": 984
  }, {
    "country": "Spain",
    "visits": 711
  }, {
    "country": "Netherlands",
    "visits": 665
  }, {
    "country": "Russia",
    "visits": 580
  }, {
    "country": "South Korea",
    "visits": 443
  }, {
    "country": "Canada",
    "visits": 441
  }, {
    "country": "Brazil",
    "visits": 395
  }, {
    "country": "Italy",
    "visits": 386
  }, {
    "country": "Australia",
    "visits": 384
  }, {
    "country": "Taiwan",
    "visits": 338
  }, {
    "country": "Poland",
    "visits": 328
} ];

AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv", {
  "type": "pie",
  "language": "es",
  "startDuration": 1,
  "theme": "light",
  "dataProvider": chartData,
  "valueField": "visits",
  "titleField": "country",
  "outlineAlpha": 0.4,
  "depth3D": 15,
  "balloonText": "[[title]]<br><span style='font-size:14px'><b>[[value]]</b> ([[percents]]%)</span>",
  "angle": 30,
  "export": {
    "enabled": true
  },
} );
```

```css
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/pie.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/amcharts/3.21.6/plugins/export/lang/es.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>

<div id="chartdiv" style="width: 640px; height: 400px;"></div>
```

Pero si descargo esas librerías, las guardo en una carpeta como **/amcharts** y las llamo así:

```js
<script src="/amcharts/amcharts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/amcharts/pie.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/amcharts/export.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="/amcharts/export.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="/amcharts/es.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/amcharts/light.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Esto me genera el siguiente error:
[image]

Comment: Acabo de probarlo en mi local y he conseguido que me funcione, podrías poner una captura de tu carpeta amcharts?

Comment: Has probado a quitarle la '/' al principio de cada ruta?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uno de los problemas que creo que te está causando eso es la carpeta de tu local donde tienes el `amcharts`. Te recomiendo que te descargues sus fuentes y lo descomprimas en tu carpeta `amcharts` pero con su estructura lógica de carpetas.

Te quedaría así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Además deberás cuadrar el src de cada js y css con su correspondiente ruta, quedando por ejemplo amcharts.js de esta manera

```
<script src="amcharts/amcharts.js"></script>
```

o el `export.min.js` de esta otra manera ya que está en una sub carpeta:

```
<script src="amcharts/plugins/export/export.min.js"></script>
```

Recuerda también quitar el `/` inicial que tienes en cada una de tus rutas ya que sino irá a buscar desde el raíz

Te dejo tambien aquí una prueba que he hecho en local es un rar que tiene una carpeta con un index y la carpeta amcharts.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/23niqb69atvj9nd/Test%20AmCharts.rar?dl=0

Comment: Efectivamente me dio solución, no creí que requiriera tenerlos ordenados y todo eso, bueno. fue la solución. Gracias,

Comment: Al final es la ordenación es necesaria ya que si entre ellos se hacen referencia la harán de manera relativa pero pasando por las carpetas como estén inicialmente

Comment: Ok gracias. 
PD: no tuve necesidad de quitar los **/**. Para volver a la raíz se requieren de **..** antes del **/**. Saludos, nuevamente gracias.